# cosign - api :error when call to SignatureFieldCreateSign

Tags: cosign-api

I want to sign PDF document, I use CoSign API, The code was written in vb6.
When I use SAPI.SignetureFieldCreateSign (create signature and sign in the document), this method need to return 0 if everything ok, but it returns -1878850896.

My code:

```
Private Sub SignPDF()
```

'Custom Values

```
Dim rc As Integer
Dim SAPI As New SAPICrypt
Dim SESHandle As New SESHandle
Dim SFS As New SAPILib.SigFieldSettings
Dim TF As New SAPILib.timeFormat
Dim fileType As SAPI_ENUM_FILE_TYPE
Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
Dim objFile As File
Dim objFolder As Folder

Dim strFolderPath As String
Dim flags As Integer
Dim filePath As String  'PDF file to sign
Dim username As String  'CoSign account username
Dim password As String  'CoSign account password
Dim domain As String  'CoSign account domain
Dim sigPageNum As Integer  'Create signature on the first page
Dim sigX As Integer  'Signature field X location
Dim sigY As Integer  'Signature field Y location
Dim sigWidth As Integer  'Signature field width
Dim sigHeight As Integer  'Signature field height
Dim timeFormat As String  'The display format of the time
Dim dateFormat As String   'The display format of the date
Dim appearanceMask As Integer  'Elements to display on the signature field


'Initialize variables
fileType = SAPI_ENUM_FILE_TYPE.SAPI_ENUM_FILE_ADOBE   'Type of the file to sign - PDF
flags = 0
strFolderPath = "C:\Users\jennya\Desktop\pdfFiles\"
username = "MyUsername"
password = "MyPassword"
domain = ""
sigPageNum = 1
sigX = 145
sigY = 125
sigWidth = 160
sigHeight = 45
timeFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
appearanceMask = SAPI_ENUM_DRAWING_ELEMENT.SAPI_ENUM_DRAWING_ELEMENT_GRAPHICAL_IMAGE Or _
                 SAPI_ENUM_DRAWING_ELEMENT.SAPI_ENUM_DRAWING_ELEMENT_SIGNED_BY Or _
                 SAPI_ENUM_DRAWING_ELEMENT.SAPI_ENUM_DRAWING_ELEMENT_TIME
```

'Instantiate and Init SAPI

```
'Initialize SAPI library
rc = SAPI.Init
If rc <> SAPI_OK Then
    MsgBox "error initializing SAPI", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    'Exit Sub
End If
```

'HandleAcquire

```
'Acquire SAPI session handle
rc = SAPI.HandleAcquire(SESHandle)
If rc <> SAPI_OK Then
    MsgBox "Failed in SAPIHandleAcquire"
End If
```

'Logon

```
'Personalize SAPI Session
rc = SAPI.Logon(SESHandle, username, domain, password)
If rc <> SAPI_OK Then
    MsgBox "Failed to authenticate user"
End If
```

'Defining signature field settings

```
'Define signature field settings
SFS.Page = sigPageNum
SFS.x = sigX
SFS.y = sigY
SFS.Width = sigWidth
SFS.Height = sigHeight
SFS.appearanceMask = appearanceMask
SFS.SignatureType = SAPI_ENUM_SIGNATURE_TYPE.SAPI_ENUM_SIGNATURE_DIGITAL
SFS.DependencyMode = SAPI_ENUM_DEPENDENCY_MODE.SAPI_ENUM_DEPENDENCY_MODE_INDEPENDENT
TF.dateFormat = dateFormat
TF.timeFormat = timeFormat
TF.ExtTimeFormat = SAPI_ENUM_EXTENDED_TIME_FORMAT.SAPI_ENUM_EXTENDED_TIME_FORMAT_GMT  'Display GMT offset
SFS.timeFormat = TF
```

'Signing

```
Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject 'creates a new File System Object reference

If objFSO.FolderExists(strFolderPath) Then 'check if Source folder exists
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath) 'get Source folder
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files 'for every file in the folder.

        filePath = objFile.Path

        'Create and sign a new signature field in the document
        rc = SAPI.SignatureFieldCreateSign(SESHandle, fileType, filePath, SFS, flags, "")
        If rc <> SAPI_OK Then
            MsgBox "Failed in SAPISignatureFieldCreateSign"
        End If
    Next
Else
    MsgBox "Folder not exists"
End If
```

'Cleaning Up

```
'Release user context
rc = SAPI.Logoff(SESHandle)
If rc <> SAPI_OK Then
    MsgBox "Failed to Logoff"
End If
SAPI.Finalize
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2):

The error you got "-1878850896" when converted to Hex is 900302B0.
If you look this error up in the SAPI Reference Guide (you can find an online version under: http://www.arx.com/api - see exact location [here](http://docs.arx.com/sapi/Default.htm#doc/Appendix%20E%20SAPI%20Signing%20Verifying%20Error.htm#_Toc383004680%3FTocPath%3DSAPI%20Local%7CAppendices%7C_____5)) you will find the following:

SAPI_ERR_TOO_MANY_CERTS_TO_SELECT_FROM
Failed to get the default certificate. The user has more than one certificate and SAPI cannot determine which one should be used as the default.
0x900302b0

This indicates that the CoSign account with which you were trying to sign contains more than a single signing certificate, and in the your SAPI code you did not indicate the default certificate to use for signing.

Ari